# CruiseControl.Net modification check datetime parse error

Tags: tfs, msbuild, cruisecontrol.net

everytime cruise control checks for TFS modifications, we get the following error:

```
BUILD EXCEPTION
Error Message:  System.FormatException: Die Zeichenfolge wurde nicht als gültiges 
DateTime     erkannt. bei System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi,
DateTimeStyles styles) bei    
ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.VstsHistoryParser.ParseChangeSet(StringBuilder 
changeSet) bei ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.VstsHistoryParser.Parse(TextReader 
vstsLog, DateTime from, DateTime to) bei 
ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.Vsts.GetModifications(IIntegrationResult from, 
IIntegrationResult to) bei 
ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.QuietPeriod.GetModificationsWithLogging
(ISourceControl sc, IIntegrationResult from, IIntegrationResult to) bei 
ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.QuietPeriod.GetModifications(ISourceControl 
sourceControl, IIntegrationResult lastBuild, IIntegrationResult thisBuild) bei 
ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.IntegrationRunner.GetModifications(IIntegrationResult from, 
IIntegrationResult to) bei 
ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.IntegrationRunner.Integrate(IntegrationRequest request)
Project:    JW.Consumer.DB
Date of build:  2011-03-01 08:56:13
Running time:   00:00:01
Integration Request:    Build (IfModificationExists) triggered from continuous
```

Force build works well.
We use TFS 2010 and CC.Net 1.6
Our ccnet.config looks like this:

```
<sourcecontrol type="vsts" >
  <server>http://tfsserver1:8080/tfs</server>
  <project>$/ProjectXy</project>
  <workingDirectory>C:\WorkingDir</workingDirectory>

  <cleanCopy>false</cleanCopy>
  <autoGetSource>true</autoGetSource>
  <force>true</force>
  <deleteWorkspace>false</deleteWorkspace>
</sourcecontrol>

<triggers>
  <intervalTrigger name="continuous" seconds="300" buildCondition="IfModificationExists" initialSeconds="30" />
</triggers>
```

Does anybody know a solution?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is there's bug with different date format (there are some [bugs](http://jira.public.thoughtworks.org/browse/CCNET-2025;jsessionid=8F99BE6470470E42774287431F019E83?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aworklog-tabpanel) still [open](https://groups.google.com/group/ccnet-user/browse_thread/thread/293b7b0fcf04fd69?hl=ja&pli=1) with no reply).
Try to modify date & time system regional settings.

HTH